# How to show axes of a confidence ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I know how to plot a confidence ellipse for a two-dimensional dataset, using:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
```

The global syntax being:

```
matplotlib.patches.Ellipse(xy, width, height, angle=0, **kwargs)
```

But I didn't find in the documentation how to **also** draw the two major and minor axes of the ellipse...
I guess that some instruction should be used within the **kwargs** argument, but I can't find which ones.

Comment: For an angle of `0`, you can plot the horizontal axis using `plt.plot((xy[0]-width/2, xy[0]+width/2), (xy[1], xy[1]))`

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-confidence-ellipse-py)? Will the ellipse always be at `angle=0`? Are you just looking to draw lines across the major and minor axes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined method or kwarg to draw the axes but you can use the [`corners`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.get_corners) property to easyly get the axes endpoints:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Path, PathPatch
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))
ellipse = Ellipse([1, 2], 3, 4, angle=50, fill=False)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
ax.autoscale_view()

c = ellipse.get_corners()
axes = np.vstack([(c[0]+c[3])/2, (c[1]+c[2])/2, [np.nan, np.nan], (c[0]+c[1])/2, (c[2]+c[3])/2])
ax.add_patch(PathPatch(Path(axes), ls=':'))
```

[image]

Comment: `jared`, didn't undersdant your question mark. For me, draw lines across the major and minor axes is the same thing than drawing the major and minor axes...

`gboffi`, I am sorry, your formulation is unclear to me...

`Stef`, thanks, I will investigate your solution with a personal dataset. Anyway, doesn't look as simple as I expected.
I thought this sort of obvious operation would have been more basic; too bad...